# Minifilter Driver and System cache. Unable to write to physical disk

Tags: caching, filesystems, minifilter

First of all, this is not about memory mapped file.

I implemented minifilter driver from ms minifilter sample "swapbuffer".
And successfully swapped some specific data when IRP_MJ_WRITE is passed in.
But when the system cache is emptied (i.e, reboot) all swapped buffer was not applied to the file.
I checked right after buffer swapped and It was perfectly swapped.
But after I empty the system cache, Its gone.
How is this possible?
Minifilter driver can't change anything to the buffer to write on disk?

I dont know exactly but I can guess that this is about the windows cache and memory manager. But must it apply the swapped content when its cache is being empty?
Im gonna read the book "NT file system internal" to find out, but anyone in here may be able to show me the the reason.

Comment: I'm reading the book "NT File System Internal". This book is perfect for me. Now I can vaguely understand that this was system cache related. I didn't install my minifilter with inf file. I installed it via service manager and stopped the Minifilter manually before Turnning off my pc. So my filter didnt do anything when system cache flushing. I didn't finished reading the book, so this maybe not right. Ill post bakc when I can sure about this.

Comment: Yeah, my guess seems right. When an irp_mj_write irp is being handled by I/O manager, I/O manager seek the file stream first in system cache not right into physical disk, except some special cases. I think I stopped my minifilter before that system cache flushed. So it left nothing swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can tell for sure. The reason why I failed to alter the buffer contents was my stupid encryption algorithm plus my ignorance about cache manager. When I copy the file, writing operation occurs twice. To physical disk, and to the cache. I dont know which one comes first yet. :p My encryption algorithm was just simply doing bit wise operation. So if it does that twice, its just decrypted plain text. That was the problem.
So I altered code to encrypt on irp that writes to physical disk, IRP_NOCACHE, it works as I meant it would be.

U wont even imagine how I hated myself for this stupidity.
Tons of articles were aleady on Osr.